# Pipes in c linux to connect 3 processes to execute a command

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

My task is to write a C program that executes the command "ls -l /bin/?? | grep rwxr-xr-x | sort". There are 3 child processes where each of them executes one of the commands separately and sends the result through a pipe to the next child process. I'm using a Swedish modified verision of debian so the error message is in Swedish, but i'll translate the error i get, it's something along the lines of: sort: failed to status -: unknown fileidentifier.

Maybe it's my pipes that do not work as intended, I'm not too sure about the close() commands. I'm pretty sure the error comes from the pipes. Would be grateful if someone could run the program and get the english error message.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <assert.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <string.h> 


int main() 
{ 
    int ret;  
    int fds1[2], fds2[2], fds3[2]; 
    char buf[20]; 

    pid_t pid; 

    ///initiating pipes 
    ret=pipe(fds1); 

    if(ret == -1){ 
        perror("could not pipe"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 

    ret=pipe(fds2); 

    if( ret == -1){ 
        perror("could not pipe"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 

    ret=pipe(fds3); 

    if (ret == -1){ 
        perror("could not pipe"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 

    pid=fork(); 

    if(pid==-1){ 

        fprintf(stderr,"fork failed"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    if(pid==0){ 
        ///CHILD 1 

        close(1); 
        dup(fds1[1]); 

        close(fds1[0]); 
        close(fds1[1]); 

        close(0); 
        execlp("/bin/sh","bin/sh", "ls-l /bin/??", (char *)NULL); 
    } 
    else{ 
        wait(0); 
    } 

    pid=fork(); 

    if(pid==-1){ 

        fprintf(stderr,"fork failed"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    if(pid==0){ 

        close(0); 
        dup(fds1[0]); 

        close(fds1[0]); 
        close(fds1[1]); 

        close(1); 
        dup(fds2[1]); 

        close(fds2[0]); 
        close(fds2[1]); 

        execlp("/usr/share/grep/", "grep", "rwxr-xr-x", NULL); 
    } 
    else{ 
        wait(0); 
    } 

    close(fds1[0]); 
    close(fds1[1]); 

    pid=fork(); 

    if(pid==-1){ 

        fprintf(stderr,"fork failed"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    if(pid==0){ 

        close(0); 
        dup(fds2[0]); 
        close(fds2[0]); 
        close(fds2[1]); 

        execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
    } 
    else{ 
        wait(0); 
    } 

    close(fds2[0]); 
    close(fds2[1]); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting the code in Swedish, forgot to change that and I'm new here, dont know how to edit my text now that it's posted. Anyway, the last execlp command i know is definetly wrong. Any1 knows how to run sort with execlp?

Comment: There is an "edit" link below the text of your question and the tags, on the left.  Click it to edit your question.

Comment: The `p` in `execlp` means that it searches the path automatically, so you can just specify `execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);` without path.

Comment: Thank you. The sort command seems to be right now but im getting the error "invalid file identifier".

Comment: @JeanDoe, and when you do edit it, be sure to explain more specifically what "does not work" means.

Comment: When I got the right sort command from you I received an error message. I have edited my post. My program now gives an error message which gives us a lead.

Comment: To get error messages in "non-localized" (normally US-English) form, it's usually sufficient to set `LC_ALL=C` in the command's environment.  For example `LC_ALL=C ./yourprogram`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems, but before I discuss them, let me introduce you to a flavor of one of my favorite preprocessor macros:

```
#define DO_OR_DIE(x, s) do { \
    if ((x) < 0) { \
        perror(s); \
        exit(1);   \
    } \
} while (0)
```

Using this macro where it is applicable can clarify your code by replacing all the boilerplate error checking.  For example, this:

> ```
> ret=pipe(fds1); 
>
> if(ret == -1){ 
>     perror("could not pipe"); 
>     exit(1); 
> }
> ```

becomes just

```
DO_OR_DIE(pipe(fds1), "pipe");
```

That makes it a lot easier to see and focus on the key parts of the code, and it's easier to type, too.  As a result, it also reduces the temptation to skip error checks, such as those for your calls to `dup()`.

---

Now, as to your code.  For me, it exhibits not just the one misbehavior you now describe in your question, but three:

- It emits an error message "bin/sh: ls-l /bin/??: No such file or directory".
- It emits the error message you describe, "sort: stat failed: -: Bad file descriptor".
- It does not terminate.

The first error message pertains to multiple problems in the arguments to your first `execlp()` call.  If you want to launch a shell and specify a command for it to run, as opposed to a file from which to *read* commands, then you must pass the `-c` option to it.  Additionally, you've omitted mandatory whitespace between the `ls` and its arguments.  It looks like you want this:

```
execlp("/bin/sh","sh", "-c", "ls -l /bin/??", (char *)NULL);
```

Setting aside the second problem for the moment, let's turn to the failure to terminate.  You have several problems in this area, falling into these categories:

- Holding pipe ends open where you should ensure them closed
- Calling `wait()` at the wrong points

When you set up a pipe between two processes, you generally want to make sure that there are no open file descriptors on either end of the pipe other than one on the write end held by one process, and one on the read end held by the other process.  Each end should be open exactly once, in exactly one process.  Since the processes being connected invariably inherit these file descriptors from their parent, it is essential that the parent close its copies (except that the parent will want to keep one open in the event that it itself is one of the communicating processes).

The process on the read end of a pipe will not see EOF on that pipe until *all* open file descriptors on the write end are closed.  Child processes running programs such as `grep` and `sort` that read their input to its end will hang indefinitely if the write end of the pipe is not completely closed.

That can be a particularly perverse problem when the child reading the pipe also has a copy of the write end of that pipe, unused, *or if one of its siblings does*.

Additionally, the whole point of a pipeline is that the processes involved run concurrently.  If you `wait()` after starting one before starting the next, then at minimum you prevent such concurrency.  Worse, however, that can also cause your program to hang, because a pipe has finite buffer capacity.  If the child is writing output to a pipe, but no one is reading it, then the pipe's buffer can fill to capacity, at which point the child blocks.  If the parent is waiting for the child to finish before launching the process that will drain the pipe, then you have a deadlock.  Therefore, you should start all the processes in the pipeline first, then wait for them all.

Having fixed such problems in your code, I find that the program emits a different error for me:

> execlp: No such file or directory

(The specifics of this message derive from the nature of my fixes.)  This should be especially concerning, because if `execlp()` fails then it returns in the process in which it was called.  In your cases, control will then fall right out of your `if` statement, into the code intended only for the parent to execute.  For this reason, it is essential to handle errors from `execlp()`.  At minimum, add a call to `exit()` or `_Exit()` immediately after.

But what's failing?  Well, it's the `grep` this time.  Note that you specify the command to execute as `"/usr/share/grep/"` -- that trailing `/` is erroneous, and the path itself is suspect.  On my system, the correct path is `/usr/bin/grep`, but since we're using `execlp`, which resolves the executable in the path, we might as well omit the path altogether:

```
execlp("grep", "grep", "rwxr-xr-x", (char *) NULL);
```

*Et voilà*!  After making that correction as well, your program runs for me.

---

Additional advice: do not use `dup()` when you care what file descriptor number you want the duplicate to have, such as when you're trying to dup onto one of the standard streams.  Use `dup2()` for that, which has the additional advantage that you don't need to close the specified file descriptor first.

Comment: Thank you John. I replaced my exec calls with yours and removed my waits and I do now get a similiar (not identical) result from running my program compared to writing "ls -l /bin/?? | grep rwxr-xr-x | sort" in the terminal. My program is missing the first row, the "bin/cp" row that is. So I suspect something is still wrong.

My program is not terminating as you mentioned above as a problem. I think I'm handling the pipes incorrectly. If you have the correct version of my program, I would be very grateful if you could put it here so i can learn how the pipes are to be handled. Thank you

Comment: Edit: the "bin/cp" line is there but on the line of the command prompt, read my answer below for the update, I have used dup2() instead of dup like you recommended. But my program does not terminate, I think something is still wrong with my pipes.

Comment: I disagree with your macro (I find that less clear than the written out error-handling - well, except for the pointless assignment to `ret` in the original), but I've upvoted your answer as the rest of it is excellent.

Comment: @JeanDoe, my answer addresses the non-termination issue already.  Correcting the misplacement of your `wait()` calls is only part of the solution; you must also handle closure of the pipe ends appropriately, as I discussed.

Comment: @TobySpeight, the point of the macro is not that it makes the error handling more clear, it's that it makes *everything else* -- *i.e.* the program's primary structure and logical flow -- more clear.  But of course, YMMV.